# Long running requests with asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Apologies for asking with what may be considered redundant, but I'm finding it extremely difficult to figure out what are the *current* recommended best practices for using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`.

I'm working with an API that ultimately returns a link to a generated CSV file. There are two steps in using the API.

1. Submit request the triggers a long running process and returns a status URL.
2. Poll the status URL until the status_code is 201 and then get the URL of the CSV file from the headers.

Here's a stripped down example of how I can successfully do this synchronously with requests.

```python
import time

import requests

def submit_request(id):
    """Submit request to create CSV for specified id"""
    body = {'id': id}
    response = requests.get(
        url='https://www.example.com/endpoint',
        json=body
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response

def get_status(request_response):
    """Check whether the CSV has been created."""
    status_response = requests.get(
        url=request_response.headers['Location']
    )
    status_response.raise_for_status()
    return status_response

def get_data_url(id, poll_interval=10):
    """Submit request to create CSV for specified ID, wait for it to finish,
       and return the URL of the CSV.

       Wait between status requests based on poll_interval.
    """
    response = submit_request(id)
    while True:
        status_response = get_status(response)
        if status_response.status_code == 201:
            break
        time.sleep(poll_interval)
    
    data_url = status_response.headers['Location']
    return data_url
```

What I'd like to do is be able to submit a group of requests at once, and then wait on all of them to be finished. But I'm not clear on how to structure this with asyncio and aiohttp.

One option would be to first submit all of the requests and then use `await.gather` (or something) to get all of the status URLs. Then start another event loop where I continuously poll the status_urls until they have all completed and I end up with a list of data URLs.

Alternatively, I suppose I could create a single function that submits the request, gets the status URL, and then polls that until it completes. In that case I would just have a single event loop where I submit each of the IDs that I want processed.

If some pseudo code for those options would be useful I can try to provide it. I've looked at a lot of different examples where you submit requests for a bunch of URLs asynchronously -- [this for example](https://realpython.com/python-async-features/#asynchronous-non-blocking-http-calls) -- but I'm finding that I get a bit lost when trying to translate them to this slightly more complicated scenario where I submit the request and then get back a new URL to poll.

Comment: I would go for the alternative, i.e. create a single function that requests the csv and polls the status page. It's cleaner and if one of the requests fail, the others are still executed.

Comment: Agreed, the solution described in the paragraph beginning with "alternatively" is the way to go. (Just create the session once and pass it to the function.) You could also have two functions and two calls to `await asyncio.gather(...)` - it's not like `await gather` has to be the last thing in an adync function. Generally in asyncio you need just one event loop and should use it consistently. If you think you need multiple event loops, it's very likely that you're using asyncio indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

FYI based on the comments above my current solution is something like this.

```python
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get_data_url(session, id):
    url = 'https://www.example.com/endpoint'
    body = {'id': id}
    async with session.post(url=url, json=body) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        status_url = response.headers['Location']
        
    while True:
        async with session.get(url=status_url) as status_response:
            status_response.raise_for_status()
            if status_response.status == 201:
                return status_response.headers['Location']
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def main(access_token, id):
    headers = {'token': access_token}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        data_url = await get_data_url(session, id)
        return data_url
```

This works though I'm still not sure on best practices for submitting a set of IDs. I think [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) would work but it looks like it's deprecated. Ideally I would have a queue of say 100 IDs and only have 5 requests running at any given time. I've found some examples like this but they depend on [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) which is also deprecated.

Comment: I've realized that I don't think `gather` and `Queue` are deprecated, just the explicit passing of the `loop` parameter.